# How do I remove all discord roles?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have several servers where I would like to delete all the roles that I previously created, but their number leaves much to be desired .. I created a command that removes one role. Please help create a command that will remove all roles from the server discord

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def delrole(ctx, *,role_name):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=role_name)
  if role:
    try:
      await client.delete_role(ctx.message.server, role)
      await client.say("The role {} has been deleted!".format(role.name))
    except discord.Forbidden:
      await client.say("Missing Permissions to delete this role!")
  else:
    await client.say("The role doesn't exist!")
```

Comment: `for role in ctx.message.server.roles: [your deletion logic here]` should do just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lukas Thaler said you could just cycle through all of the roles in the server, but if you want to just remove a few roles, you can try this.

```
@client.command()
async def delrole(ctx, *, roles: discord.Role):
    for role in roles:
        try:
            await client.delete_role(ctx.message.guild, role)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await client.say("Missing Permissions to delete this role!")
```

The format to use this command would be: !delrole @role1 @role2 @role3, etc. With however many roles you want.